# Laravel 5.4 save() in a loop

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to 'conquer' Laravel, but some concepts still elude me.

Lets take this code:

```
public function updateMenuGroup($groupId, $label, $icon, $sort, $userId)
{

  /*get model to be updated by id*/
  $updateGroups = MenuGroups::findMany($groupId);

  /**
   * set attributes to be updated 
   * I loop, since I get collection of models fetched by findMany()
   */
  foreach($updateGroups as $update)
  {
    /**
     * label (group name) is passed as an array of group names
     * for every language, so I am fetching them by using 
     * language passed by model fetched by findMany (find gets only first mode)
     */
      $update->label = $label[$update->lang]; //array
      $update->icon = $icon;
      $update->sort = $sort;
      $update->system_employee_id = $userId;

      $update->save();
  }
}
```

$update->label carries an array, with different values for different language - say I have 'en', 'de' languages.

When I run code above, only 'en' is being written - overwriting values of 'de'.

Can someone, please, give me some pointers, as to why above happens?

Comment: Where did you instantiate $update?

Comment: $updateGroups = $this->menuGroups->findMany($groupId); gets me collection of models and I loop through them using foreach. $update is a model from collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to instantiate update model class inside loop.

foreach($updateGroups as $update)
  {
    /**
     * label (group name) is passed as an array of group names
     * for every language, so I am fetching them by using 
     * language passed by model fetched by findMany (find gets only first mode)
     */
      $update=New ModelClass(); 
      $update->label = $label[$update->lang]; //array
      $update->icon = $icon;
      $update->sort = $sort;
      $update->system_employee_id = $userId;

      $update->save();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I tested that option as well by looping $label array and just doing Laravel pseudo-static (pseudo, as it is not static at all, when you dig into it - just look like it) - GroupModel::where('lang', $lang) - $lang being a key in $label loop. And it worked. I was kind of hoping, you can use models fetched by hasMany() directly. It seems you cannot. I also used $this->menuGroups->find($groupId)->where('lang', $lang)->where('id', $groupId). This kind of creates interesting situation. You need where('id', $groupId), or you get single language doubled. Interesting. Thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert array to one attribute.

Try to use implode function.

like this.

```
$update->label = implode(",", $label[$update->lang]);
```

Comment: $label is an array. $label[$update->lang] this is not an array anymore, but a string gotten from an array using $update->lang key, e.g. $label['en'].